# Кликабельные блоки знаков у нового пользователя в профиле

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, профиль-участника

У [меня в профиле](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/15479/suvitruf?tab=profile) эти блоки не кликабельны:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А у [нового юзера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/325531/suvitruf-test?tab=profile) кликабельны:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ведут почему-то на [страницу меток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags).

Comment: Что-то не кликаются

Comment: @älёxölüt забавно. Они не кликаются, если смотреть другим юзером. Если открывать страницу этим юзером, то у него кликаются.